# How to use http requests from webhooks to make trade using binance api?

Tags: python, webhooks, algorithmic-trading, binance, tradingview-api

I used Robswc/tradingview-webhooks-bot to create http requests by using http requests. It's working fine but I want to now use the requests I get to make trades on binance. However, I'm pretty new to coding and am super lost. Any help on how to integrate the http requests from webhooks to the binance api would be appreciated :))

edit(s):

- Thanks Ali! I've used a server to collate alerts from tradingview
  through a server. The requests I get are in GET method. However, I
  want to use these GET methods in conjunction with python so that it
  is actually useful and was wondering if anyone had any ideas on how I
  could go about to doing that. :)
- Thanks Andrey! The issue is that I'm using binance futures which aren't supported on the platform :(

Comment: Hi, You need to provide what you did until now. so others can correct you. If you are searching for tutorial you'd better google it.

Comment: Thanks Ali!
I've used a server to collate alerts from tradingview through a server. The requests I get are in GET method. However, I want to use these GET methods in conjunction with python so that it is actually useful and was wondering if anyone had any ideas on how I could go about to doing that :)

Comment: You can use thirdparty descisions. For example https://alertatron.com/

Comment: Thanks Andrey! The issue is that I'm using binance futures which aren't supported on the platform :(

Comment: HTTP request aren't gonna work since, except if you use electron or alertatron or something like that. In my opinion this is bad practice. Check this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A5_w7X8FnLQ Also check my comment on the video on how you should use it. This is cheaper in code and better in safety.